# Passing kwargs into a python string for rendering rather then using %s/%d...etc

Tags: python, string, templates

About a week ago I saw a script using kwargs in the string template. Unfortunately I can't re-find that script so I thought I'd ask to see if anyone knows of a way that I can pass kwargs into the string builder rather then just args.

Here is the desired result:

```
"""%name went to the store.""" %( name = John )
```

Naturally, this won't work and for the life of me I cannot remember the proper syntax.

Comment: It works great.  The syntax is here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations.  Please use search where possible.  It saves you some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"""%(name)s went to the store.""" % {"name": "John"}
```

or

```
"""%(name)s went to the store.""" % dict(name="John")
```